# Lambda Reference Common Python Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I have a class and some constants defined that 10 or more lambda functions will need. Currently, I have packaged the common code into each lambda function. Unfortunately, if I change the common code I have to repackage all 10 lambda functions and upload the changes.

Ideas that I had considered:

- Lambda return a class with defs and constants – not feasible, lambda returns JSON
- Try to magically load the common code from S3 – (not sure how and do not
  really like that there are multiple steps to update a lambda
  function)
- Packaged the common code into each lambda function – (current design)

***What is the best method for referencing common python code for lambda?***

Comment: Only reasonable way I found so far is option 3. You could use option 1 and ast library, but you're in for one hell of a ride if you want to do that.
Use Serverless.com framework, it helps with a lot of pains of option 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I did was an automatic deployment script in python for my lambdas + API gateway (+ intern usage of S3 etc). You can deploy your lambda without changing your API gateway endpoint, and be doing so, all your lambdas can be updated in one click without modification of the interaction with outside of your AWS box. 
Inside, you can manage the bounds with S3 or dynamoDB or anything else automatically. It's an investment at the beginning, but it's definitely worth it, even more in your case with many lambdas.

Your solution of a constant provider could be a short term good strategy, but you'll need to be sure that your old lambdas will work with your news constants, so either you are limited in your provider's evolutions, either you'll have to manage many versions of your provider. Lambdas are meant to be easily deployed and replaced.